# Different results of glmer in R when the order of data is shuffled

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I found that glmer in lme4 package sometimes gives slightly different results, e.g. AIC/BIC and/or fixed/random factors, when model is a bit complex and the order of data is shuffled. Therefore, I'm picking up the best results in terms of AIC or BIC. Does this make sense?

The second question is where is the divergence coming from? In theory, the order of data should not matter as long as the i.i.d assumption is made. The different results suggest that glmer uses (perhaps iterative) algorithms that depend on initial values.

I would be grateful if you could provide any feedback or suggestions.

For your information, here is the sample code I tested, assuming that multiple practitioners make binary diagnoses based on four types of features in medial images.

```
# data generation
nPracts <- 40 # number of practitioners
nImages <- 100 # number of medial images
var1 <- rep(seq(-20,20,10), 20) # 4 image features
var2 <- c(rep(-20,20), rep(-10,20), rep(0,20), rep(10,20), rep(20,20))
var3 <- rep(seq(-20,25,5), 10)
var4 <- c(rep(10,20), rep(0,20), rep(-20,20), rep(20,20), rep(10,20))
fix1 <- 0.05 # 4 fixed factors
fix2 <- 0.5
fix3 <- 0.1
fix4 <- 0.3
rand1 <- rnorm(nPracts, mean=0, sd=0.1) # 4 random factors (practitioner-dependent)
rand2 <- rnorm(nPracts, mean=0, sd=0.05)
rand3 <- rnorm(nPracts, mean=0, sd=0.01)
rand4 <- rnorm(nPracts, mean=0, sd=0.03)

data <- data.frame()
for (j in 1:nPracts){
  for (i in 1:nImages){
    z <- var1[i]*(fix1+rand1[j])+var2[i]*(fix2+rand2[j])+var3[i]*(fix3+rand3[j])+var4[i]*(fix4+rand4[j])
    pr <- 1/(1+exp(-z))
    y <- rbinom(1, 1, pr) # binary diagnosis
    data<- rbind(data, c(j, var1[i], var2[i], var3[i], var4[i], y))
  }
}
colnames(data) <- c('practitioner', 'var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4', 'diagnosis')
data$diagnosis<- factor(data$diagnosis)
data$practitioner <- factor(data$practitioner)

# refit model 5 times to see the divergence
for (k in 1:5){
  set.seed(123+k)
  data2 <- data[sample(nrow(data)),] # change data order
  fit <- glmer(diagnosis~ var1+var2+var3+var4+(0+var1|practitioner)+(0+var2|practitioner)+(0+var3|practitioner)+(0+var4|practitioner),
               data=data2, family=binomial(link="logit"))
  print(fit)
}
```

These are two samples results from the last block. They are slightly different.

```
      AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance  df.resid 
 511.9535  568.5999 -246.9767  493.9535      3991 
Random effects:
 Groups         Name Std.Dev.
 practitioner   var1 0.099567
 practitioner.1 var2 0.080622
 practitioner.2 var3 0.002188
 practitioner.3 var4 0.046851
Number of obs: 4000, groups:  practitioner, 40
Fixed Effects:
(Intercept)         var1         var2  
    0.39222      0.05796      0.56366  
       var3         var4  
    0.10046      0.31254
```

```
      AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance  df.resid 
 512.0151  568.6616 -247.0076  494.0151      3991 
Random effects:
 Groups         Name Std.Dev.
 practitioner   var1 0.100646
 practitioner.1 var2 0.080578
 practitioner.2 var3 0.006207
 practitioner.3 var4 0.044535
Number of obs: 4000, groups:  practitioner, 40
Fixed Effects:
(Intercept)         var1         var2  
    0.26154      0.05492      0.54916  
       var3         var4  
    0.10028      0.30373
```